# Moment and Cumulant Notation

Tags: statistics, notation, moment-problem, cumulants

I recently started working with moments and cumulants for some statistical analysis and among my research I can’t figure out some of the notation.

It will be written as:

M<sub>2,1</sub> and C<sub>4,3</sub>

I know M represents moment, and 2 represents the second order, but I don’t know what the 1 represents or how to calculate it.
Likewise for the C being cumulant, 4 the fourth order, and I don’t know the 3.

If I could get a direction on where to look, and an example on how to calculate them, that would be very helpful.
Thank you!